# Batch File - Find file and Replace

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Basically I have created a batch file which copies a file within `FOLDER A` and then renames the file with the date on the end and pastes it into `FOLDER C`.

Before this takes place I am looking to find out how I would set up a FIND function to search through `FOLDER B` to see if it has a file with the same name.

If it does contain the same name as the file in `FOLDER A` then I want it to copy that file add the date on the end and paste it into `FOLDER C`.

Lets say:

- *wav file is in FOLDER A
- FIND *wav file in FOLDER -B to see if it exists.
- If the *wav file does exist
- then copy this to FOLDER C
- then re-name *wav with the date on the end

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please post your code so we don't have to re-write it.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and (real/not pseudo) code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

### IF EXIST

cmd has a builtin `IF EXIST` that checks to see if a file exists, and the analagous `IF NOT EXIST`. (See `IF /?` or [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)) Something like this would do what you describe.

```
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_FILE%" COPY "%SOURCE_FILE%" "%TARGET_FILE%"
```

### File/Path Parsing

cmd has some means of parsing paths, however, all the useful features are contained within the `FOR` command (See `FOR /?` or [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)).

I usually start with a typical environment variable, e.g. `%SOURCE_FILE%`, give it to `FOR` and allow `FOR`'s substitution behavior to get either the parent dir, filename, extension, etc.

Suppose you wanted the base name of the file (no containing directory). You could accomplish that like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ("%SOURCE_FILE%") DO SET "SOURCE_FILE_BASE=%%~ff"
```

Now, `SOURCE_FILE_BASE` would contain the base name of the file. (Note: the syntax of `FOR` changes when you use it in a script vs at the interactive shell. The use of `%%` is what a script needs.)

### Combined

Based on what you describe, supposing you have a path to a file saved in `SOURCE_FILE` and the directory where you wish to copy the file to, `TARGET_DIR`, you could accomplish what you describe by doing something like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ("%SOURCE_FILE%") DO SET "SOURCE_FILE_BASE=%%~ff"
SET "TARGET_FILE=%TARGET_DIR%\%SOURCE_FILE_BASE%"
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_FILE%" COPY "%SOURCE_FILE%" "%TARGET_FILE%"
```